# Location of source for a midrash of Zipporah on Har Sinai?

Tags: sources-mekorot, midrash, moshe-rabbeinu, har-sinai

A friend was expounding a midrash to me about Zipporah but was unaware of the provenance. The story involves Zipporah, prior to meeting Moshe, searching for her lost flocks near Har Sinai. She directed prayers to the God of Avraham and then found her sheep drinking water at the foot of the mountain. Noticing that the water seemed to be coming off the mountain itself, she tried to find the source and met an angel. The angel took her by the hand and led her to the summit which was the color of sapphire. The angel said words to the effect of 'My daughter, I've seen your heart and you will become part of a house that will be a blessing, and you will marry its leader. And one day you all will return to this mountain.' She then departed from the mountain, and the spot where she had prayed now had a green bush growing, which later became the burning bush.

Does anyone happen to know a source for this midrash?
Many thanks

Comment: Meir, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! I've never heard of this story before, but I can certainly see why it's compelling. I look forward to seeing you around. You might be interested in checking out some of our 200 other [tag:midrash] questions.

Comment: This story does not appear in the אוצר אישי התנ׳ך.

Comment: @user6591 Is it possible that this is a modern take on the story designed to appeal to certain sensibilities?

Comment: @Isaac I'm not sure what you mean. The OP is seeking a medrash. It seems from this source that no such medrash or anything similar exists. If it is a complete fabrication, for whatever reason, it is still not a medrash.

Comment: @user6591 I think that's what Isaac Kotlicky was suggesting.

Comment: While I could buy that she davened to Hashem, saying that this Midrash took place after they rejected idolatry but before Moshe came along, the rest of this seems to be a jumble of Pesukim related to Har Sinai (the sapphire from Shemos 24:10, the angel being at the top of the mountain from 3:2, the message that they would return to this mountain from 3:12).